# Hide div only when scroll is not available on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to hide a `div` but only when the `page` is showing `100%`, I'm trying to do this since I've added a `ScrollToTop` and `ScrollToBottom` button to the page, this page has a list of servers that you can toggle to only show `Offline` servers but not the online ones, in case the list is so small that the page is fully shown (so no scroll bar is present)

Is it possible to hide a div only when scroll isn't possible or not?

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="javascript:;" id="scrollToTop">&#x25B2;</a>
  <a href="javascript:;" id="scrollToBottom">&#x25BC;</a>
</div>
```

Should only be visible if the page is scroll-able (all i.e. 200 servers are shown), but if this button is pressed:

```
<li><a href="#" id="hidelive" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" style="float:right; text-decoration:none; margin-right: 5px">Toggle Deployments <i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a></li>
```

only i.e. 3 servers are shown, so everything on the website fits on screen (no scroll bar)

The `wrapper` should be hidden too.

[View all servers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ad3S.jpg)

[View only offline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wk1A7.jpg)

Comment: Please share your code or an equivalent for that so that we can understand it clearly.

Comment: Why not show the div after scroll instead?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-show-some-particular-div-after-scroll-100-px

Comment: I've added screenshots of the page, so on the second picture, you can see the scroll bar is gone because the screen matches the webpage. so the up and down button should be hidden too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this

```
if($(document).height() <= $(window).height()) {
    $('div').hide()
}
```

Comment: That is what I mean yes! I can't however get it to work.

Comment: Please explain what is not working. Did you changed the selector to $('.wrapper').hide()

Comment: Yeah, but when the scroll bar disappears the div doesn't.

Comment: Is there any delay? A setTimeout with one or more seconds could help then.

Comment: I tried adding the timeout but it still doesn't do anything.